# Как сделать переводчик оффлайн?

Tags: машинное-обучение, поиск-программ, перевод

Результат должен быть работающий переводчик оффлайн.
То есть нужен http API похож на то что есть у Google Translate и Яндекс Переводчик.

Нашёл несколько вариантов:

- [Microsoft Translator](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/p/translator/9wzdncrfj3pg?activetab=pivot%3Aoverviewtab) установить на Windows, скачать словари, и как-то через http передать там запросы на перевод
- [Apertium](https://www.apertium.org), этот вариант уже ближе к реальности, но тут не понятно как настроить всё...
- [Apache Joshua](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JOSHUA/)
- [Promt](http://www.promt.com/corporate/developers/pts/), на самом деле это идеальный вариант, но он очень дорогой
- Установить Android на ПК, а там уже Google Translate, только опять-же будет вопрос передачи http запросов

Нужен перевод целых предложений, а не только отдельных слов.
Может быть есть какя-то консольная утилита. Или может быть под linux что-то есть.

По какому из вышеперечисленных вариантов лучше искать ещё информаций?

Comment: В целом вопрос понятен, но не совсем ясно, зачем вам какой-то http API, если переводчик оффлайн.

Comment: чтобы данные можно было по локальной сети передать

Comment: Если что вот ссылка на EN SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53076666/how-to-make-an-offline-translator